# on click even't doesn't seem to fire on my android device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css

I'm calling a function `showModal` on click of the `#btn-game-rules`

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-game-rules', showModal);
```

The function called is:

```
    showModal : function()
    {   
        $('#' + $(this).data('modal'))
        .show()
        .addClass('animated bounceIn')
        .one(Game.animationEnd, function() {
            $(this)
            .removeClass('animated bounceIn')
        });
    }
```

what it does is essentially look up data-modal atribute of the button that was clicked and based on that show a modal (note classes that are added are just some classes from [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)) to make modal appearance more entertaining. This works on my mac / computer, but doesn't work on my android device running android 5, in chrome. Modal does not appear on the screen.

Not sure if it is necessary, but here is css related to that specific modal (and all others):

```
.modal {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    left: 30%;
    right: 30%;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: does it work on your browser? if yes then use touchstart event for touch devices

Comment: @Sushil it does, so do all other events that start on click. So I assume it should trigger function showModal as well, as it is done same way as all others.

Comment: can you try using touchstart?

Comment: @Sushil just tried actually, still no modal appears. I also checked if it is positioned properly on mobile by setting its display to block and it is indeed there.

Comment: hmm.. can you remove the positioning of the div and see if it appears? or can you share a quick jsfiddle?

Comment: @Sushil, simply removing display: none from modal does show it on my mobile screen and I can click a close button that dismisses it, but when I click this show modal button it does not appear like it should and does in my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bad reference to the callback. `showModal` is a member of some object, so you will need to reference it like this:

`$(document).on('click', '#btn-game-rules', theObject.showModal);`

Comment: Sorry, I thought I simplified it correctly for this question, it is indeed a member of Game object and in my code I call it with 'Game.showModal'

Comment: Try making a jsfiddle or something where you can reproduce the issue. It will help us help you... or maybe it will make you realize where the mistake is.

Comment: Had two dots in Game..showModal, have no idea how it worked in browser, but you pointed me to right place.